# Resetear registro por año

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Estoy realizando un par de formularios en JAVA con IDE Netbeans, y me ha salido una pequeña complicación...
Donde tengo un numero de formulario infinito por año, pero al partir un nuevo año este debe quedar en 0

```
void generarNumeroRegistro() {
    String sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(nregistro)+1 as nregistro FROM muestras WHERE laboratorioejecutante <> 'LADIOX' ORDER BY nregistro DESC LIMIT 1";
 //   conectar cc = new conectar();
    try {
        java.sql.Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            lb_registro.setText(rs.getString("nregistro"));
        }
        if (lb_registro.getText().isEmpty()) {
            lb_registro.setText("00000+1" + "-" + "2018");
            lb_registro.repaint();
            System.out.println("REGISTRO VACIO");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

El tema es que este codigo, con esa modificación del año quedaria obsoleto...

Me podrian dar alguna ayuda con esto porfa...

Comment: obtener al año de acuerdo a la fecha del sistema con java 8 puedes usar ´ `LocalDate.getYear()`

Comment: @isaac pero como podria setear que en un nuevo año se resetee el contador a 0  ??

Comment: Se me ocurre que deberias tener una función que valide si el día anterior es un año diferente, y si es asi, hacer los updates para volver a cero.

Comment: Te sugiero usar primero DateFormat para que puedas establecer el parámetro que te permitirá hacer el resto de los análisis. Necesitas un patrón de comparación pero primero debes hacer el patrón.